# How to use Swift library with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swiftui

Can the following libraries be used in SwiftUI?

https://github.com/weilsonwonder/WWCalendarTimeSelector

If you add "pod 'WWCalendarTimeSelector'" to the podfile and update it, it will be displayed as below when importing.

> no such module 'WWCalendarTimeSelector'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add it to the pod file like this:

```
platform :ios, '13.4'

target 'yourapp' do

  pod 'WWCalendarTimeSelector'

end
```

Then navigate in the terminal to the location of your Pod file and type in the terminal the command:

```
pod install
```

The Pod file is located in the folder of your app. If there is no Pod file yet type the command: `pod init` in the terminal first. Make sure to `cd` into your app folder first.

Wait for it to finish. Now launch your Xcode project by opening the `yourapp.xcworkspace` file found in the app directory. There you now should be able to import:

```
import WWCalendarTimeSelector
```

If this throws errors try to rebuild it by pressing on your keyboard Command+B.

If this didn't help either try restarting Xcode. I personally have had the bug that it didn't recognise some imports before restarting it.